# Left Align Text In Text Area

Tags: html, css

I can not figure out how to do this, here is my syntax, but is leaving text centered in the text area.

```html
<textarea name="mytextarea" cols="50" rows="5" style="align-content:center; overflow:auto; border:6px outset #000000;" >
    Doggie: 100 - 94
    Cat:    93 - 74
    Apple:  73 - 50
    Orange: 49 - 0
    </textarea>
```

**EDIT**
This is my full code and a screenshot of what it looks like when I run it:

```
%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <textarea name="mytextarea" cols="50" rows="5" style="text-align:left; overflow:auto; border:6px outset #000000;" >
            Doggie: 100 - 94
            Cat:    93 - 74
            Apple:  73 - 50
            Orange: 49 - 0
        </textarea>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2**
This is screenshot of what it looks like in my browswer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYodW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7gTU.png)

Comment: your code works fine on its own. you should search in the parent elements' styling if there is any attribute that centers everything.

Comment: Do you want it centered or left, with or without a left padding?

Comment: This is your pre-rendered aspx code. please post the code after its been rendered by visual studio - ie. what you see when you inspect the page in the browser.

Comment: @Banana - attached is image of browser code.  If you were needing to see something different, please let me know.

Comment: @RedLightGreenLight i needed to see the source of the page, when you right click the page and select view source. but i see that your issue is already solved...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the `textarea` is white space sensitive, try removing the white spaces like in this example

```html
<textarea name="mytextarea" cols="50" rows="5" style="align-content:center; overflow:auto; border:6px outset #000000;" >
Doggie: 100 - 94
Cat:    93 - 74
Apple:  73 - 50
Orange: 49 - 0
    </textarea>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar you gave 2 identical answers which centered on the text aligning, first they were wrong, then after you edited them they were correct answers but to a different question. you only provided an answer which solves op's issue in the end and at the bottom of your 2nd answer. Colns provided a clean solution which directly solves op's issue without any irrelevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Change `align-content:center` to `text-align:left`

Or you can just add `text-align:left` and see if that works.

Comment: Same issue as before, text is centered in the text area